# Udemy.z01 is not RAR archive

Tags: rar, unzip

$ unrar e Udemy.z01

UNRAR 6.02 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2021 Alexander Roshal

Udemy.z01 is not RAR archive
No files to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.z01` file is not necessarily a file in the `RAR` format. This means you cannot unpack it using `unrar`.

[Info about z01](https://fileinfo.com/extension/z01)

> A Z01 file is the first of multiple files that make up a split archive created with select file compression utilities, such as Corel WinZip and WinRAR. It contains one or more files that have been compressed with Zip compression to save space.

Split RAR archives are (in my experience anyway), usually named `.r00`, `.r01`, `.r02`, ...